# React - vertically align text and icon

Tags: css, reactjs

I have tried all things to align vertically an icon and a text, Code:

```
<Danger color="secondary" style={{ flex:1,justifyContent: "center",alignItems: "center" }}>
  <ErrorOutline
    className={classes.warning}
  />
  <text numberOfLines={1} style={{ textAlignVertical: "center" }}>
    The last job was canceled
  </text>
</Danger>
```

Things that I've tried : `display, justifyContent, alignItems, flex, flexDirection, etc.`

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: if you want vretical use `dispaly:block` to icon instead `flex` (`flex` is align horizontal)

Comment: To be more clear :D I want the text and icon to be on the same line, but the text to be at the centre of the icon

Comment: `text and icon to be on the same line` so it horizontal not vertical am I right? you have any  image to describe it?

Comment: use display: flex

Comment: as mentioned, I've already tried using display: 'flex'

Comment: please put your code here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cgjuzk

Comment: do you have sufficient height in element so that icon can align itself vertically?

Comment: Display flex should work, we can't guess what your problem is by looking at some JSX

Answer (score 0):

Try out this inside render of react code

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', lineHeight: '40px'}}>
  <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/user-male-circle-filled.png" height="40"/>
  <div>Welcome User!!!</div>
</div>
```

And for clear understanding you can find the entire React code for this particular example in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/r6yLmu8t/

You need to give lineHeight for the div tag in which the image/icon and text are there. And make sure that the icon/image height is equal to the lineHeight given to the div.

Hope this will achieve your need of text and icon to be on the same line and text to be at centre of icon/image

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button light>
    <View style={{flexGrow: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Icon name='arrow-back' />
        <Text>Back</Text>
    </View>
</Button>
```

Comment: I think this is react-native, not reactjs (I am a beginner in react, but I believe element "View" doest not exist in reactjs)