# React Native: Image doesn’t vetrically align center in nested text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, react-native

#### Problem Statement

I need to nest **multiple images** inside a **paragraph**. Had it been a **single line of text**, I would’ve wrapped a **`<View>`** with **`flexDirection: 'row'`**. As that doesn’t solve the usecase, I wrapped all the texts and images with **`<Text>`**.

#### Image For Reference

As per my current approach the images **do nest but don't align centrally with the text**. I have tried a few fixed which you can check under **`styles.fix`**

In each highlighted section, **the envelope image is aligned with the baseline of text** but rather it **must be verticaly aligned centre within each highlighted red box**.

[image]

#### Code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

import Img from './img.png';

export default () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.rootContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          <Text>This is a long paragraph with icon here </Text>
          <Image style={[styles.img, styles.fix]} source={Img} />
          <Text> on the next line as well </Text>
          <Image style={[styles.img, styles.fix]} source={Img} />
          <Text> and and and and and here too </Text>
          <Image style={[styles.img, styles.fix]} source={Img} />
          <Text> but the icons are not center aligned with the text.</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  container: {
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  img: {
    width: 23,
    height: 15,
  },
  fix: {
    /**
     * `tried lowering position with relative positioning but didn't work`
     * top: 10,
     * position: 'relative',
     *
     * `margin didn't work either as it messed up icon proportions`
     * marginTop: 10,
     *
     * also tried wrapping Image in a View with
     * marginTop or relative positioning but the
     * results were same as the above two
     */
  },
});
```

Comment: did u find any way ?

Comment: Yes, I did but it seems inefficient. I'll add the solution in some time.

Comment: Hi bro can u add, it would be really helpful as i havent got any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?
[React - vertically align text and icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647821/react-vertically-align-text-and-icon)

I don't see using align-items here with flex. Try with alignItems: "center" wrapping in View, to align them vertically.

Comment: No, I wouldn’t check because it's a **React** question. Any answer to it won't solve my usecase. And `alignItems: "center"` won't work as it can align only the root `<Text>` and not it's children `<Text>` or `<Image>`.